# On what Stack Exchange site would I ask a question about translating a text from Bengali?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am trying to translate something in Bengali to English and only two third-party translation sites helped me. Is there any site in the Stack Exchange Network where I can ask for a translation from Bengali to English and someone who knows the language can answer?

Comment: _... and only 2 translation sites give me some help. Is there a site where I can get some help?_ So what you've got in the 2 other sites wasn't helpful? Are you talking about Stack Exchange sites or looking for 3rd party stuff? The [tag:site-recommendation] tag is meant to find appropriate sites within the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: 3rd party sites, sorry. Corrected question

Comment: The third party sites couldn't help me. I am looking to Stack Exchange for help

Comment: AFAIK there's no translation service (at least not Bengali) available at any of the Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Is there any site in Stack Exchange where I can ask for a translation in Bengali and someone who knows the language can answer?

Comment: As mentioned, I'm afraid no.

Comment: Would it be worth going to Area 51 and creating a new site about the language?

Comment: @AChildofGod - probably not. I can't see there being the audience for such a site.

Comment: @AChildofGod even the existing language SE sites don't do translations - they will explain certain words and phrases, but not translate a whole text for you. Creating a new site takes months and will probably not result in a site that will even do what you want.

Comment: What third-party services have you tried? We use [Transifex](http://transifex.com) for localization, and they have a huge community of translators in almost every language that are very proficient (they just work from home). The most basic plan would allow you to get in touch with very fluent people and (quite possibly) get it done. As for a site? We don't have anything that could help you right now, besides some advice on possibly better third-party services, which I just gave :)

Comment: Google Translate and the other I don't remember.

Comment: Since there is no site in the Stack Exchange Network, is there any good (preferably free) sites that could do translations (at least Bengali to English)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a number of sites available to ask for language specific concerns and subtleties. See them listed under the [culture/recreation](https://stackexchange.com/sites#culturerecreation) category.

Unfortunately Bengali isn't a language listed there.

Anyway even these sites I've mentioned aren't meant as translation services. If you already have a translation, you might be able to ask for subtleties to get clarified.

It's a bit like the Oxford dictionary or the German Duden, which don't offer plain translations, but clarifications of terms and concepts (and are written in their native language of course).

Comment: But providing translation services ain't going to work there in the first place.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Sure,  and the sites I mentioned aren't translation services of course.